# How to use prove this $p^4\equiv p\pmod {13}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

> Let a prime number $p$, and $n$ a positive integer such $$p\mid n^4+n^3+2n^2-4n+3.$$
> Show that $$p^4\equiv p\pmod {13}.$$

A friend of mine suggested that I might be able to use the results [problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3611903).

Comment: I suspect the argument will run parallel to [this old one of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2385221/11619), or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2091011/11619). Not sure about the details, but I'm optimistic. I don't have the time to think about the details right now, sorry. May be later tonight? Anyway, I added the tag [tag:algebraic-number-theory] to attract the right people to the scene.

Comment: Anyway, the splitting behavior of the prime $p$ in the cyclotomic field $\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_{13})$ is reflected in this result. It is quite possible that there is a lower level argument. One of the linked questions was allegedly from a Chinese high school contest, so... :-)

Comment: For n=3 we get $117=9\times 13$. So there is some problem with statement of question.

Comment: @sirous What is the problem there? Both $p=3$ and $p=13$ satisfy the congruence $p^4\equiv p\pmod{13}$, no?

Comment: I think @Piquito is not true

Comment: The question is from the Miklós Schweizer contest, see http://www.bolyai.hu/SCHWEITZER/megoldasok_Schweitzer2018.pdf

Answer (score 8):

I highly respect  subtle mathematics  but here, at MSE, I give priority to the elementary.  I think mainly of beginners who, for obvious reasons, do not understand anything if the reasoning is of medium high level.

We have to prove that the polynomial $f(x)=x^4+x^3+2x^2-4x+3$ (which, say it, is always divisible by the prime $3$ because
$f(n)=n(n-1)(n+1)^2+3(n^2-n+1)$)  is such that putting $$f(n)=\prod_{i=1}^{i=r}p_i^{\alpha_i}$$  where $n$ is an arbitrary natural,  it is verified  for all $p_i$  the congruence
$$p_i^4\equiv p_i\pmod{13}$$ so it is clear that the primes $p_i$ belong to a certain class excluding a lot of other primes.

We can write $$4f(n)=(2n^2+n+5)^2-13(n+1)^2$$  from which $$4f(n)\equiv(2n^2+n+5)^2\pmod{13}$$
A straightforward calculation gives for $g(x)=(2x^2+x+5)^2$
$$g(\mathbb F_{13})=\{0,4,10,12\}$$ so we have (adding details) in $\mathbb F_{13}$  (where $0=13k;1=13k+1$, etc)
$$\begin{cases}4f(n)=0 \hspace{10mm}\text {for }  n=0\space  \text {and 3}\\4f(n)=4\hspace{10mm}\text {for }  n=2,4,8,11\\4f(n)=10\hspace{8mm}\text {for }  n=7,9,10,12\\4f(n)=12\hspace{8mm}\text {for }  n=1,5,6\end{cases}$$ 
On the other hand the inverse of $4$ modulo $13$ is $10$ so we have

$$\begin{cases}f(n)= 0\hspace{10mm}\text {for }  n=0\space  \text {and 3} 
\\f(n)=1\hspace{10mm}\text {for }  n=2,4,8,11\\f(n)=9\hspace{10mm}\text {for }  n=7,9,10,12\\f(n)=3\hspace{10mm}\text {for }  n=1,5,6\end{cases}$$
Now the primes $p_i$ above can be only $13$ and those of the form $13k+1,13k+9$ and $13k+3$.

This property can be easily verified because if $p^4\equiv p\pmod{13}\iff p(p^3-1)=13$k then $p^3-1$ is divisible by $13$ when   $p\ne13$. In fact
$$1^3-1=0=13\cdot0\\\hspace{5mm}9^3-1=728=13\cdot56\\3^3-1=26=13\cdot2$$
But none of the nine integers below are divisible by $13$
$$2^3-1\\4^3-1\\5^3-1\\6^3-1\\7^3-1\\8^3-1\\10^3-1\\11^3-1\\12^3-1$$

Comment: Good stuff. Can you do something similar [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2091011/11619)? I can add a bounty as a sweetener :-)

Comment: Or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2385221/11619).

Comment: I shall try but it is not easy to prove with elementary means what has been solved by thick artillery. Remenber however that, according to certain sources, the legend of an elementary proof of Fermat Last Theorem   still stands.

Comment: For any  $n$ the polynomial is divisible by $3$  and $3$ is the only prime such that $3^4≡3 \ mod (13)$, so $p=3$ and $p^4 ≡p \ mod (13)$

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen: I have solved your second link on divisibility by $7$. Do you want I send you it somewhere? Or here itself in the comments. (obviously I am not chasing for a bounty).

Comment: I appreciate you not being interested in points. When awarding bounties I see myself as a collector of beautiful pearls (or artful math). That's why I started [the Pearl Dive](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102837/pearl-dive). Anyway, if you don't want a bounty, I will honor that request (and tip my hat instead). Feel free to post the solution there so that others can also see it.

Comment: @sirous I still don't get what you want to say with that comment. For example when $n=4$ the quartic has value $339=3\cdot 113$, and $113^4\equiv113\pmod{13}$.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen: I dit. The message I was send has in Pearl Dive appeared  just in latex but not clarify. Maybe I have did an error in the way to send the message.

Comment: I think is somewrong,when $n\equiv 0\pmod {13}$ then $4f(n)=(2n^2+n+5)^2\equiv 5^2\pmod {13}$ not $o$

Comment: oh,I found this solution is also wrong,becuase this don't true !,if prime $p$ such $p|f(n)$,and $f(n)\equiv \pmod {13}$,then $p\equiv 1\pmod {13}$ I think this is not right

Comment: I dont understand, dear friend. Anyway your are right maybe.Good luck.

Comment: @Piquito I don't get how is it proved that the primes $p_i$ can only be $p_i \equiv 0,1,3,9 \pmod{13}$ (you stated it after computations of $f(n)$ modulo $13$)

Comment: @AnasA.Ibrahim: I have work on a similar problem reducing it to two possibilities only but these are hard to prove with an elementary way. Respecting the problem of this post not necessary a heavy calculation because just few verifications are needed. Good luck.

Comment: @AnasA.Ibrahim: Calculate the nine last numbers and verify easily that none of them ara multiples of $13$.

Answer (score 4):

The key idea here is that the polynomial $ P(X) = X^4 + X^3 + 2X^2 - 4X + 3 $ is not arbitrarily chosen. If $ \alpha $ denotes a root of this polynomial over $ \mathbf Q $, then $ \mathbf Q(\alpha) $ is the unique quartic subfield of $ \mathbf Q(\zeta_{13}) $ - in fact, we have

$$ \alpha = \zeta_{13} + \zeta_{13}^{3} + \zeta_{13}^{9} $$

(where $ 1, 3, 9 $ are the fourth powers mod $ 13 $, of course.) If the polynomial $ P $ has a root mod $ p $, then the prime $ p $ splits completely in the quartic subfield, and that's equivalent to the subfield being fixed by the Frobenius element corresponding to the prime $ p $, which is the automorphism given by extending $ \zeta_{13} \to \zeta_{13}^p $. It's easy to see this automorphism fixes the subfield if and only if $ p $ is a fourth power mod $ 13 $, which is a condition equivalent to $ p^4 \equiv p \pmod{13} $. The proof is completely analogous to the one of quadratic reciprocity. (This argument ignores the case when $ p = 13 $, which is the only ramified prime in $ \mathbf Q(\zeta_{13}) $, but in this case the claim $ p^4 \equiv p \pmod{13} $ is trivially satisfied.)

A more down-to-earth version of the same argument can be given by considering the Frobenius automorphism over $ \mathbf F_p $, in which case not quite as much algebraic number theory needs to be brought to bear on the question, but the spirit of the argument remains the same.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $\ne3,13$. Let $\zeta\ne1$ be a $13$th root of unity in $F_p$ and let
$$ 
a=\zeta+\zeta^3+\zeta^9, \quad
b=\zeta^2+\zeta^6+\zeta^{12}, \quad
c=\zeta^4+\zeta^{12}+\zeta^{24}, \quad\text{and}\quad
d=\zeta^8+\zeta^{16}+\zeta^{48};
$$
it can be verified that 
$$ (x-a)(x-b)(x-c)(x-d) = x^4+x^3+2x^2-4x+3. \tag{$*$} $$
(This is how the polynomial $(*)$ was constructed.)

By the condition, $n$ is a root of $(*)$; w.l.o.g $a=n\in F_p$.

Notice that $c=\frac{3-2a-a^3}{3}\in F_p$, and
$$
(x-\zeta)(x-\zeta^3)(x-\zeta^9) = x^3-ax^2+cx-1. \tag{**}
$$
This polynomial is either irreducible over $F_p$ or all its roots are in $F_p$; in both cases $\zeta\in F_{p^3}$. Then $ord(\zeta)=13$ divides $|F_{p^3}^*|=p^3-1$.

Answer (score 0):

Using pari/gp.

```
? f(n)=n^4+n^3+2*n^2-4*n+3;
?
? for(r=0,12,print1(f(Mod(r,13))", "))
Mod(3, 13), Mod(3, 13), Mod(1, 13), Mod(0, 13), Mod(1, 13), Mod(3, 13), Mod(3, 13), Mod(9, 13), Mod(1, 13), Mod(9, 13), Mod(9, 13), Mod(1, 13), Mod(9, 13),
```

I.e. $f(n)\equiv 0,1,3,9 \pmod{13}$.

Solve $p^4\equiv p \pmod{13}$:

```
? polrootsmod('p^4-'p,13)
%1 = [Mod(0, 13), Mod(1, 13), Mod(3, 13), Mod(9, 13)]~
```

Any powering and product primes of form $0,1,3,9 \pmod{13}$ is again $0,1,3,9 \pmod{13}$.

Thus $p\mid f(n) \iff p^4\equiv p\pmod {13}$.

Answer (score 0):

**Proof for the case when $n\bmod 13 \neq 3$**

Let $n\bmod 13 = k$. Then, by substituting $k=0,1,\ldots,12$ and $k\neq 3$, we have
$$\left[n^4+n^3+2n^2-4n+3\right]\bmod 13= \left[k^4+k^3+2k^2-4k+3\right]\bmod 13\in\{1,3,9\},$$
which are all  powers of $3$. Now, notice that $$n^4+n^3+2n^2-4n+3\bmod p=0\implies p\bmod 13 \in\{ 1,3, 9\},\tag{1}$$
since  $p\bmod 13\neq 0$ as $p$ is a prime number. 
Finally, we deduce that
\begin{align}
p^4\bmod 13&=\left[p^4-p + p\right]\bmod 13\\
&=\left[p(p-1)(p^2+p+1)+ p\right]\bmod 13\\
&=\left[p(p-1)(p^2+p-12) + p\right]\bmod 13\\
&= \left[p(p-1)(p-3)(p+4)+ p\right]\bmod 13\\
&=\left[p(p-1)(p-3)(p-9)+ p\right]\bmod 13 \\
&= p\bmod 13.
\end{align}
where we use $(1)$.

Answer (score 0):

My take on this problem is to solve the quartic equation using the quartic formula. To use this formula, the $x^3$ term needs to be eliminated, which can be done by substituting $y=x-\frac {1}{4}$. The result is, after quite a bit of algebra, is

$y^4+\frac{13}{8} y^2 - \frac{39}{8}y -\frac{1053}{256}=0$

To solve this, use the cubic resolvent. For $y^4+py^2+qy+r$ this is

$z^3+2pz^2+(p^2-4r)z-q^2=0$

This yields

$z^3+\frac{13}{4}z^2-\frac{221}{16}z-\frac{1521}{64}=0$

Solve this using the cubic formula, which involves eliminating the $z^2$ term with $w=z-\frac{13}{16}$. After a lot more algebra, one finds that the roots are $\frac{13}{4}$, $\frac{-13+2\sqrt(13)}{4}$, and $\frac{-13-2\sqrt(13)}{4}$. That means that a root of the reduced quartic is

$\frac{1}{2}  (\sqrt(\frac{13}{4})+\sqrt(\frac{-13+2\sqrt(13)}{4}) + \sqrt(\frac{-13-2\sqrt(13)}{4})$

Going back to the original quartic, one get, as one of the roots

$-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{2}  (\sqrt(\frac{13}{4})+\sqrt(\frac{-13+2\sqrt(13)}{4}) + \sqrt(\frac{-13-2\sqrt(13)}{4})$

Now if we take this polynomial mod 13, all the square root stuff beyond the $-\frac{1}{4}$ is zero, so a root mod 13 is $-\frac{1}{4}$. By trial and error or solving a diophantine equation, one gets that $-\frac{1}{4}=3$ mod 13. Then note that $3^4 = 3$ mod 13, which gives the intended result.

Answer (score -1):

We will have modulo $13$ all the time. Notice that $$N:= n^4+n^3+2n^2-4n+3 \equiv (n^2-6n-4)^2 \equiv (n-3)^4$$

Clearly $13\mid N\iff 13\mid n-3$, so we assume $p\ne 13$ and thus $13$ does not divide $n-3$. Say prime divisor $p$ of $N$ is good if $p^4{\equiv}p$.

Suppose the statment is not true, so there exists a prime $q$ which is not good.

Also we can assume that there is no good prime divisor of $N$: if $p\ne 13$ is good than we can divide $N$ by $p\equiv p^4$ modulo $13$ and then observe $N' = N/p^4$ modulo $13$.  Also we can reduce $N$ with all divisors of $N$ of form $d^4$. So if we make now a prime factorisation for $N$ modulo $13$ we have $$N\equiv  2^a4^b5^c6^d7^e8^f10^g11^h12^i$$
(clearly there is no $0,1,3$ and $9$) where all the exponents are nonnegative and less than $4$ and at least one is positive. Of course, we can reduce this even more:
$$N\equiv  2^{a+2b+d+3f+g+2i} 3^{d+i} 5^{c+g}7^e11^h$$
or $$N\equiv  2^x 3^y 5^z(-6)^e(-2)^h$$
where or exponents are nonegative and less than $4.$ Again we can assume if $y=0$ (else we divide $N$ by $3$ modulo $13$). So we can write:$$ N\equiv  (-1)^{3z+e+h} 2^{x+3z+e+h} = (-1)^t2^{x+t}$$
where $t= 3z+e+h$. So $$N\equiv   -1\pm2,\pm4,\pm8$$
Now this can not be of the form $(...)^4$ and we have a contradiction.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen Can you spot a mistake here Jyrki, please?